# Do 401k contributions need to be invested? Can it be left as cash in the account?

Tags: 401k

As title. Since the market is a bit volatile now, wondering if I can keep the 401k contributions as cash and invest them later. Or does it necessarily need to be invested in one of the options that the brokerage provides? Thanks!

Comment: [Why I cannot find a “Pure Cash” option in 401k investments?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44703/why-i-cannot-find-a-pure-cash-option-in-401k-investments) seems to be identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

401(k) accounts are required to have a number of choices. There will be a fund that's low low risk, likely made up of T-Bills of very short duration. Not quite a money market fund. It may have a zero return if rates shoot up quickly, but a tiny risk of less than zero in a given year.

Comment: Despite it not having anything to do with the actual question I would have liked you to add that timing the market is a bad idea, especially for a retirement account.

Comment: A number of congressmen who sold while the market was still above 3000 on the S&P would beg to differ with you.

Comment: Agreed.... I was assuming we don't have inside information and/or it's illegal for us to trade based on inside information :)